# Why does nohup command interrupt?

Tags: bash, background-process, nohup, interrupt

I put a command in `.bash_profile` file. The command is:

```
nohup stdbuf -oL -eL sysdig -c spy_users 1>>/path/to/out 2>>/path/to/err &
```

While I am working on terminal it appears:

```
[1]+  Done                    nohup stdbuf -oL -eL sysdig -c spy_users >> /path/to/out 2>> /path/to/err
```

Whu do I have this interruption?

Comment: Why do you feel you need the `nohup`? Have you tried just putting the `sysdig` directly into your `.bash_profile` and backgrounding it?

Comment: what do you mean? how can I have better background command?

Comment: Try this: `sysdig -c spy_users 1>>/path/to/out 2>>/path/to/err &`.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to check: `stdbuf -oL -eL sysdig -c spy_users 1>>/path/to/out 2>>/path/to/err &` I will let you know ther result.